# Is Linux powershell 7.1.3 CentOS slow for you too?

Tags: linux, powershell

Running Powershell commands to login into the Microsoft Teams API is really slow compared to running them on Windows Server 2019. Same goes if I am running any other types of scripts or trying to login to other Microsoft API's. In general the functionality is slow..

A login script on Windows takes around 30 seconds, where with Linux it takes about 1.5-2 min depending on when I run it.

**Attempts to Resolve:**

I've tried 'Remove-Module PSReadLine' with no luck (I read this could slow down the processing due to font colours conversion to linux). Upgrading to the newest Powershell version 7.1.3 also did not help. I am guessing that it's probably got to do some type of Windows to Linux conversion on Microsoft's side?

Anyone have any ideas or experienced this and have been able to get the same performance as running on a Windows box?

[Login Script for Microsoft Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8rjF.png)

Comment: You mention PHP scripts.  What has PHP scripts got to do with PowerShell on Linux?   Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Hi fpmurphy, I have updated the question. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Unexpected slowness could be caused by certificate revokation list [CRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list)  checks. Different OS have different built-in trust chains, so check if disabling CRL in Linux would help.

Comment: Thanks vonPryz. Looks like this can be done via Windows, but not linux. It's also not recommended per Microsoft.